# How to randomly add form input values with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Say for example I have a pool of answers to a question in array.

How would I render out 3 random answers and 1 correct answer into the value of form inputs?

let me try this is semi-pseudo code real quick..

```
var answerList = [1, 2, 3, ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7, 8, 9, 10];

var questionIdArrays = [1]

var question1 = {

   questionId: 1,
   question: "What is 5 + 5?",
   correctAnswer: 5

  }

get random question from questionIdArrays

because questionIdArray is 1, get questionId 1

display question1's question in <h1> element

randomly display correctAnswer in 1 of the 4 input values
randomly grab 3 answers from answerList and place them randomly in the remaining 3 input values
```

Hopefuly this makes sense! The hard part is the random output of the answers, which I am confused.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
Zero the correct answer from the answerList
create loop
use Math.random() to get a number from the list
test if result is zero
  if it is then get another number
store value 
zero out result
```